# Fill a FileDialog from another macro

Tags: excel, vba, filedialog

My company has a standard model tool, which uses a standard Excel file as input.

To update inputs from an old template, you download a standard file from a platform, and use an Excel VBA sub that doesn't take any arguments (called "Upgrade engine"). When you call Upgrade engine, there is a file dialog tab that opens, to select the source file to upgrade.

To test the standard model I create templates for each release of the model for non regression testing. I would like to automate the process. I **cannot** change the code of the standard template.

I created a masterfile with my non regression use cases, their address etc. to update them one by one.

```vb
Public gParamTab As Variant
Public gHypTab As Variant

Public gSourcefolder As String
Public gBlankFolder As String
Public gTgtfolder As String

Public Const gParamTabColUseCase As Byte = 1
Public Const gParamTabColTTtgt As Byte = 2
Public Const gParamTabColTTSource As Byte = 3
Public Const gParamTabColFlagRetrieve As Byte = 4
Public Const gParamTabColTTCase As Byte = 5
Public Const gParamTabColFlagUpgrade As Byte = 6

Public Const gBlankTTName As String = "Table_Template_MVP_case"

Public Const gExtension As String = ".xlsb"


Sub init()
gParamTab = Sheets("Parameters").Range("gParamTab")
gHypTab = Sheets("NDD HYP").Range("gHypTab")

gSourcefolder = Sheets("Parameters").Range("gSourcefolder")
gTgtfolder = Sheets("Parameters").Range("gTgtfolder")
gBlankFolder = Sheets("Parameters").Range("gBlankFolder")
End Sub


Sub updateTT()

Call init

Dim lFullname_blank As String, lFullname_source As String, lFullname_tgt As String
Dim lGlobalrange As Variant
Dim lGlobaltable() As Variant
Dim lBlankTT As Workbook
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim lSearchedVariable As Variant
Dim lBlankTTupgradeengine As String
lcol = 2

For lUsecase = 2 To UBound(gParamTab, 1)
    If gParamTab(lUsecase, gParamTabColFlagUpgrade) = 1 Then
     
        lFullname_blank = gBlankFolder & "\" & gBlankTTName & gParamTab(lUsecase, gParamTabColTTCase) & gExtension
        lFullname_source = gSourcefolder & "\" & gParamTab(lUsecase, gParamTabColTTSource) & gExtension
        lFullname_tgt = gTgtfolder & "\" & gParamTab(lUsecase, gParamTabColTTtgt) & gExtension
        
        Set lBlankTT = Workbooks.Open(lFullname_blank)
        
        lBlankTTupgradeengine = gBlankTTName & gParamTab(lUsecase, gParamTabColTTCase) & gExtension & "!UpgradeEngine.UpgradeEngine"
        
        Application.Run lBlankTTupgradeengine
        
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

How can I, from another macro, after the statement `Application.Run lBlankTTupgradeengine`, the upgrade engine macro starts, and calls the following function embedded in the "BlankTT"?

```vb
Sub UpgradeEngine()

    Set wkb_target = ThisWorkbook
    Set wkb_source = macros_Fn.Open_wkb()

    [...]
```

```vb
Function Open_wkb() As Workbook

    Dim fileName As Variant

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  
        ' Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        
        ' Filter to just keep the relevants types of files
        .filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsm; *.xlsb", 1

        .Show
        
        ' Extact path
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            fileName = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        Else
            End
        End If
        
    End With
                  
    If (fileName <> False) Then
        Set Open_wkb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=fileName, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=False, Editable:=False, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
    Else
        MsgBox "This file is already open. Please close it before launching the function."
        End
    End If
        
End Function
```

This function opens a dialog box with a browse button to select the Excel spreadsheet to use as source.

How can I fill automatically this FileDialog from my code, without changing the code of the standard Excel file?

I'm trying to move a copy of the upgrade engine, but with an argument in the sub instead of the filedialog.

Comment: Do you mean automatically select an Excel file in FileDialog ? You can add  a code line like       .InitialFileName = "D:\directory_path\mysample.xlsx"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to add an optional parameter to `UpgradeEngine` - something like:

```vb
Sub UpgradeEngine(Optional wbPath as String = "")

    '...
    Set wkb_target = ThisWorkbook
    If Len(wbPath) > 0 Then
        Set wkb_source = Workbooks.Open(wbPath)  'open using provided file path
    Else
        Set wkb_source = macros_Fn.Open_wkb()    'open user-selected file
    End If
    '...
    '...
```

Then you can call it and pass in the path you want.

FYI the code in `Open_wkb` seems off (at least, the "already open" message seems wrong).  `fileName <> False` only checks if the user made a selection: it doesn't indicate anything about whether a selected file is already open or not.

Answer (score 0):

I finally copied all the modules of the target file in my own macro, made a few tweaks, and it works even better. Passing this step of the Filedialog was in fact the first step of a long and hard road. There was a lot of msgbox and other interactions so I disabled everything in my one code.